# Where does url decoding happen?

Tags: url-encoding

When considering a three-tier architecture with

1. FrontEnd Client
2. AppServer
3. Database server

and when the URL is encoded in the Browser(Frontend client) where does URL decoding happen? Is it AppServer or Database?

Br,
Hemanshu.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, the web application server will typically handle URL decoding. (I feel like I should provide more detail/explanation, but I don't know what the motivation is for asking, so I'm not sure what more to include.)

Comment: I am asking it from SQL Injection point of view. I send an encoded exploit in the query string or path parameter, depending upon who decodes it, I can modulate the attack vector.